# Need to generate graphics at random points in Android but no idea how

Tags: android, random, graphics

I need help on generating graphics at random points for my Android App but I totally have no clue on how to do it. Take for example, some icon/graphic pop up randomly and i need to 'touch' it to kill it.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Random number generation or displaying graphics?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the next - create a handler inside your activity and post a runnable with random startTime. Inside runnable execute method you can tell your pop up to actually draw.

Quick Example:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
Random r = new Random();
long time = r.nextInt(5000); //random time between now and 5s
h.postDelayed(new MyRunnable(), time);

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
public void run() {
     //show popup
}
}
```